# StreamReader get next line and skip over empty lines

Tags: c#, recursion, streamreader

I'm reading a file using a StreamReader. These files sometimes have empty lines between other lines. The number of empty lines in-between can be any number. What's the best way to have my StreamReader skip over all empty lines until a non-empty line is read?

I have a function that I call in a while loop:

```
/// <summary>
/// Moves the stream to the next non-empty line, and returns it. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="srFile"></param>
private string GetNextLine(StreamReader srFile)
{
    string line = srFile.ReadLine();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        GetNextLine(srFile);
    return line;
}
```

Everything seems fine, but for some reason this doesn't work. Whenever line isn't empty, the return line does indeed get hit, but for some reason more recursive 'GetNextLine()' calls are made. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or offer a solution?

Comment: You ignore the value of the recursive call - you probably meant `return GetNextLine(srFile)`. However, this recursion is unnecessary and dangerous (in terms of blowing the stack if you have a large file with a lot of newlines in a row) - it would be better to use a while loop in GetNextLine.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines().Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrWhitespace())` is very expressive way to achieve what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return result of your recursive call:

```
private string GetNextLine(StreamReader srFile)
{
    string line = srFile.ReadLine(); 
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        return GetNextLine(srFile); // here, but can you spot infinite loop?
    return line;
}
```

Note that you should also handle end of file. E.g. return `null` if there is no non-empty lines till the end of file:

```
private string GetNextLine(StreamReader srFile)
{
    string line = srFile.ReadLine();
    if (line == null || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
       return line; 

    return GetNextLine(srFile);
}
```

Comment: Note: for real code please do not rely on tail recursion optimization and use regular `while`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution avoids recursion and handles any number of empty lines:

```cs
private string GetNextLine(StreamReader srFile)
{
    string line;
    do
    {
        line = srFile.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
            return null; // end of file
    } while (line.Length == 0); // empty line

    return line; // here line is not empty
}
```

Comment: OP is looking to exclude lines that are all whitespace, not just blank lines

Comment: You are right. Fortunately that condition is easily applicable to the solution.